# Change Column Order of Array returned using JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I am using JSON to get the data.

What is happening the JSON-P changes the order of column and put them alphabetically.

The JSON is:

```
[{ "Grade"="pv" , "ID" = 1 , "Name" = "test" }]
```

But i actually send it ID first.

After getting this JSON i use the following line:

```
 var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
```

Then i am about to convert this array to an HTML table.

But when i bond HTML label i want to show the Column ID first and so on. (Means i can configure using jquery which column to show first).

How can i do that efficiently?

**The Question is rewritten because lot of users are not able to understand my question because of lack of my communication skills**

Eaxmple: (Whatever the format i get does not matter but using Jquery how can i able to hardcode which column to show first)

Its like changing the array column order

Thanks

Comment: The above is not valid JSON. It's a bit hard to tell what you mean by it.

Comment: @kojiro This is just an example. What ever be the JSON i will parse it using JSON.parse put it in array and then want to reorder it

Comment: @JamesMontagne After putting the JSON into an array using JSON.parse then i want to reorder it

Comment: I understand what you want to do, I want to know why.

Comment: @KamalDeepSingh I realize that, but it's important that your example JSON use at least valid JSON syntax so we can tell what you're doing. If you use `=` when you mean `:` it fundamentally changes the meaning of your question. If you think I'm nitpicky, you should see my compiler.

Comment: @kojiro I am really sorry for the same i will update it with valid JSON soon

Comment: @kojiro i have updated my question please have a look

Comment: @maxedison i have updated my question please have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data represented by an object in JSON has no inherent order, so you can't count on JSON to *maintain* an order for an unordered object. If order is important, but arbitrary, your best bet is to use an ordered object such as an array to store the data.

```
// documentation says first element is always id, second grade, third name
[[1, "pv", "test"], …]
```

Barring that, you can keep a side-by-side index in an array to help you recover the order.

```
[{
    "ordering": ["ID", "Grade", "Name"],
    "ID": 1,
    "Grade": "pv",
    "Name": "test"
}]
```

Comment: The valid JSON i will parse it using JSON.PARSE put it in array and then want to reorder it.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible with JSON. As the [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/) explains:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs

Comment: I've edited my answer with the link. It's at the top, right before the first diagram.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for specific order of things then you should store them as separate objects in an array

```
[{name:"Grade",value:"pv"}, {name:"ID",value:1},{name:"Name",value:"test"}]
```

Comment: The valid JSON i will parse it using JSON.PARSE put it in array and then want to reorder it.

Comment: @KamalDeepSingh I honestly have no idea what are you saying.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing "object" and "array". What you have here is an array of JSON objects. Arrays are sortable with [.sort()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp).